# How do I solve this Taylor Series problem?

Tags: taylor-expansion

Consider Taylor series for $f(x) = \frac{1}{x + 1}$ about $x_0 = 0$. If we use Taylor series to approximate $\frac{1}{1.01}$, how many terms in the Taylor series must be kept so that the absolute error is within $10^{-5}$?

If someone could walk me through this step-by-step, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You wrote "xnot = 0", but did you mean "x=0"?

Comment: I wanted to write a subscript 0 instead of the word "not", but didn't know how to.

Comment: To do a subscript, you use underscore. So if you write x_0 in LaTeX, then it will come out like this: $x_0$. To write a formula, put a dollar sign \$ either side of the equation: \$ x^2 \$ becomes $x^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can give a hint - this is a well known way of expanding such a fraction: $$\begin{align}&\frac1{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3+...\\\implies&\frac1{1+x}=1-x+x^2-x^3+...\end{align}$$

---

With regards to the error part of the question: your denominator is $1.01$, which equates to $x=0.01=10^{-2}$. In the above series, which terms would be necessary to be kept? What the question means is that you want the first $5$ decimal places to be correct, anything after that you don't need to worry about. So from this can you tell how many you need to keep?

Comment: Thank you. I understand that part, but what's giving me trouble finding how many terms in the Taylor series must be kept so that the absolute error is within 10^(-5). I don't even understand what that means.

Comment: Here's what I did. I used a calculator to compute a decimal approximation of 1/(1.01) and, with 5 decimal place accuracy, I got 0.99010. This is the value I got after I added the 1st 3 terms of the taylor series.(1 - .99 + 0.0001 = 0.9901 = 0.99010). So I came to the conclusion that the answer is 3. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct, as you have verified with the calculator. However you can do it without the calculator - plug $x=10^{-2}$ into the Taylor expansion above. You get $1-0.01+0.0001-0.000001+...$. Does this mean anything to you?

Comment: What's it supposed to mean?

Comment: You want accuracy to the order $10^{-5}$. The 4th term is $10^{-6}$, which is more accuracy than you need, so you don't need this term.

Comment: I've got it now. Thank you so much. That was tremendously helpful.